# Unanswered tab on the Linked Questions page shows questions with accepted and upvoted answers

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions, linked-questions

Here is a list of [questions linked to #97098](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/97098?sort=unanswered) sorted by *unanswered*.  As you can see, it shows many questions with accepted and upvoted answers, contradicting its name.

Actually, it appears to show *all* linked questions, reordered in some strange way.